# PHP - Modification time of extracted files is set to server's time zone - How to change?

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, zip, extract

So our code creates a zip file and inside it are PDF's from a specific folder. Everything works fine, except that when this zip file is downloaded to a computer and the files are extracted - the modification time for each PDF file follows the server's time zone. (Our site is on a GoDaddy shared server, and they're located in Arizona. We are located in Singapore.)

Is there a way to modify this? I have tried to set the default time zone or use touch() but no luck.

```
// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$res = $zip->open(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'MortgageWise-All-Reports.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

if ($res === TRUE) {
 // Create recursive directory iterator
 /** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
 $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath)
 );

 foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
 // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
  if (!$file->isDir()) {
   // Get real and relative path for current file
   $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
   $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath));

   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

   //touch($filePath, );

   // Add current file to archive
   $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
  }
 }

 // Zip archive will be created only after closing object
 $zip->close();
}
else {
 echo "File not created.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying to set the timezone at the start of the script, before you create the ZIP, rather than in the foreach loop.

But with that being said I don't believe it will make much difference as the PDF files already exist? And therefore will already have those properties assigned to them!

Do you have access to Web Host Manager or similar? If you have a VPS or Dedicated server, you can change the time zone of the server yourself.

EDIT: sorry, you already stated you are on a shared server, would highly recommend a VPS to give you full control over these settings, should only be $50 a month

Comment: Yes, I have set the time zone at the start of the script too. And I saw that on GoDaddy forums – that you can set the time zone if you have VPS/Dedicated server. I don't think my client would want to pay extra just for that.